# how to receive data from ESP8266 access point

Tags: android, arduino-esp8266

I configured ESP8266-01 as an access point. After connecting to ESP wifi network as a client, on-click events of the android app try to send data using `AsyncTask` which uses a socket to send data to ESP88266 (access point). by on-click events, I can send `led/on` or `led/off` commands. hence led will toggle when I press two buttons. I used a toast in `public void onPostExecute(final String Data)` in `AsyncTask` to determine what data is sent back by the server(ESP) to the android app as its client. I have expected to receive a kind of JSON response containing "on" or "off" as acknowledge since ESP Sends the response to the client(`client.println(s);`) when I click on buttons I can turn led on or off but received data on `public void onPostExecute(final String Data)` section of the app always contains null.ESP default access point IP address is 192.168.4.1 then using a browser I can send 192.168.4.1/led/on to turn led on and the browser immediately shows`{"data":{"message":"success","value":"off"}}`as JSON response but I need to have an acknowledgment for the designed android app.
How can I get any kind of acknowledgment from ESP in my android app?

Any help is appreciated.

here are ESP code from Arduino IDE and MainActivity code of the android app.

ESP code:

```
#include<ESP8266WiFi.h>

// WiFi Definitions
const char* ssid = "DigitalCalendar";
const char* password = "Esp8266Test"; // has to be longer than 7 chars
const char* value = "";

int ledPin = 2; // GPIO 2
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {

   Serial.begin(9600);
   delay(10);
   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // turn on

   WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
   WiFi.softAP(ssid, password, 1, false);
  
   server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // Check of client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if(!client) {
    return;
  }
  
  // Read the request line
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.print(request+'\r');  
  // Match request
  if(request.indexOf("/led/on") != -1) {
     digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
     value = "on";
  } else if (request.indexOf("/led/off") != -1) {
     digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      value = "off";
  }
  
  client.flush();
  // JSON response
  String s = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
  s += "Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n";
  s += "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"success\",\"value\":\"";
  s += value;
  s += "\"}}\r\n";
  s += "\n";

  // Send the response to the client
  client.println(s);
  delay(1);
  //Serial.println("Client disconnected");
  // The client will actually be disconnected when the function returns and the client object is destroyed
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int LOCATION = 1;
Button btn1,btn2;
String command;
String networkSSID = "Esp8266TestNet";
String networkPass = "Esp8266Test";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1=findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2=findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    //------------------------------------------------------
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            command="/led/on\r";
            send_request(command);
        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            command="/led/off\r";
            send_request(command);
        }
    });
}
public void send_request(String message) {
    send_request sr = new send_request();
    sr.execute(message);
}
class send_request extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... message) {
        try {
            /*note : ip address must be in Quotation mark*/
            /*note : port doesn't need to be inside the Quotation mark*/
            Socket s = new Socket(/*ip address :*/"192.168.4.1",/*port :*/ 80);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            printWriter.write(message[0]);
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(final String Data) {
        /*Data is what you receive from your server*/
        Log.e("my_Data","Data is : " + Data);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //Assume you want to read the SSID when the activity is started
    tryToReadSSID();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && requestCode == LOCATION){
        //User allowed the location and you can read it now
        tryToReadSSID();
    }
}

private String tryToReadSSID() {
    String ssid="no ssid";
    //If requested permission isn't Granted yet
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Request permission from user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);
    }else{//Permission already granted
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        if(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED){
            ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();//Here you can access your SSID
        }
    }
    return ssid;
}
```

}

Comment: I cant use WifiConfiguration class since it is deprecated for API 29.

Comment: `and the browser immediately shows{"data":{"message":"success","value":"off"}}as JSON response b` Well nice. Why isnt that good enough for you? For your app? Sorry, i dont understand the problem. That is the acknowledgememt i would say.

Comment: `/*Data is what you receive from your server*/'` No. Data is the value returned by doInBackGround. And you returned null. Moreover you received nothing from your server. You only send/wrote a string. But you did not receive/read the response.

Comment: I used a browser to send simple data just to verify that my ESP works properly. Transporting all data by a browser from mobile or computer is not admissible for all cases. I have solved this challenge, but I need a kind of acknowledgment to check if data is received completely to ESP like what a browser receives from ESP. my main problem is about receiving data from ESP for the case while I am using my android app. received data from ESP is always null in android app, meanwhile, I have tested ESP by a browser and have received a JSON response in it.

Comment: My god you do not listen. You are receiving nothing as you do not try to receive anything.

Comment: thanks blackapps alot. can you guide me on how can I receive ESP response in doInBackGround? is there another way to get response from ESP?

Comment: There is not another way. There is only one way.

Comment: So like you sent a string writing it to the sockets output stream you can receive the response reading it from the sockets input stream.